# Save image using MediaStore, saved with wrong name and extension

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to use `MediaStore API` to save an image but it always save the file with this name
**1637955326427.jpg** and the size of the file is **0 B**.
this is the code that i use:

```
 OutputStream fos;
            ContentResolver resolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "fileName.jpg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
            Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            try {
                fos = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),list.get(0).getDocfile().getUri());
                if(bitmap!=null){
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,fos);

                    fos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

`list.get(0).getDocFile()` return a `DocumentFile` also i tested this on `API 28`
Thanks in advance

**NOTICE** this image already exist on the `External Storage`, just need to copy it.

**EDIT:** I delete this code `fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);` was duplucate. I do realy apologize. the file work fine but steal wrong name.

Comment: Are the files added to the mediaStore api to retrieve an ID from?

Comment: bitmap==null ? You are not logging or Toasting anything if.

Comment: @blackapps i debugged the code and bitmap was not null

Comment: @blackapps i tested this on android 11, it's work fine but on android 9 it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete this code `fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);` was duplicate. the image work fine but steal wrong name.

About the Wrong name and extension, i think that `MediaStore` doesn't work fine with Android 9 and lower, because i tested the same code on Android 11 and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

First lets take a look at getting write permissions for an existing image. Please note that the photopath does not necessarily exist yet but should point to the location you want your file to be saved.

```
if (!requestPhotoWritePermission(this, getImageUriFromFS(this, new File(photoPath)))) {
        return;
    } else {
        takePicture();
    }
```

This will form an overwrite request with the default camera

```
public static Uri getImageUriFromFS(Context c, File file) {
    long id = getFilePathToImageID(file, c);
    Uri fromUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,id);
    return fromUri;
}



public static long getFilePathToImageID(File imagePath, Context context)
{
    Uri mainUri;
    Cursor cursor1 = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media._ID},
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
            new String[]{imagePath.getAbsolutePath()}, null);
    long id = 0;
    if (cursor1 != null && cursor1.moveToFirst()) {

        id = cursor1.getLong(cursor1.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        cursor1.close();
    }
    return id;
}

public static boolean requestPhotoWritePermission(Activity activity, Uri fromUri) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

        boolean hasPermission = true;
        if (activity.checkUriPermission(fromUri, Binder.getCallingPid(), Binder.getCallingUid(),
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            hasPermission = false;
        }

        List<Uri> uriList = new ArrayList<>();
        uriList.add(fromUri);

        if (!hasPermission) {
            PendingIntent pi = MediaStore.createWriteRequest(activity.getContentResolver(), uriList);
            try {
                activity.startIntentSenderForResult(pi.getIntentSender(), REQUEST_OVERWRITE_PERMISSION_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This will persist the permission to overwrite or create a new picture via the camera intent

Then in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == 53) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //you'll want to take your picture here and possibly store the uri to your photo for later retrieval
            takePicture();
        }
 }
```

This will take a picture if the permission request is accepted

To Take a picture using the default intent with a provider:

1. Declare your provider in the manifest

   ```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
   ```

1.5: xml File paths file:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-files-path
    name="internal_images"
    path="files/Pictures" />
<external-files-path
    name="internal_images_alternate"
    path="Pictures" />
<external-path
    name="external"
    path="Documents" />
<external-files-path
    name="external_files"
    path="Documents" />
<cache-path
    name="cache"
    path="Documents" />
<external-cache-path
    name="external_cache"
    path="Documents" />
<files-path
    name="files"
    path="Documents" />
</paths>
```

The above will give you permission to save to the documents folder. Replace as required.

2. Utilize the provider to take the picture

   ```
   public static File dispatchTakePictureIntent(Activity activity, String photoPath) {

        Intent takePictureIntent = getCameraIntentWithUpdatedPackages(activity);
        Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile(new File(photoPath));

        Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity.getApplicationContext(), activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(photoPath));

        activity.grantUriPermission(photoURI.getAuthority(), photoUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
        //disable strict mode policies
        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
        activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        return new File(photoPath);


    return null;
   ```

   }

EDIT:
I forgot something

```
 public static Intent getCameraIntentWithUpdatedPackages(Context context) {
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo = new ArrayList<>();

    final Intent capturePhoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    resolveInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(capturePhoto, 0);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
//             For Android 11 we need to add specific camera apps
        // due them are not added during ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE scanning...
//            resolveInfo.addAll(getCameraSpecificAppsInfo(context));
    }
    capturePhoto.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

    return capturePhoto;
}
```

EDIT: Update by the name (in onActivityResult after requesting an overwrite permission)

```
Uri fromUri = MediaUtils.getImageUriFromFS(this, new File(from));
                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

                contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, 1);
                contentResolver.update(fromUri, contentValues, null, null);
                contentValues.clear();
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, new File(to).getName());
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, 0);
                contentResolver.update(fromUri, contentValues, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for ur time. the problem is i'm not trying to capture an image, this image is already exist on external storage i just need to copy it using `MediaStore`

Comment: If you get it's Id via the media store query method you can unlock the entity and then update it by it's Id and then relock it down. I'll post a code sample shortly

Comment: The image exist on a hidden folder. i tried using `MediaStore` to find it but it's not showing. so i had to use SAF

Comment: After taking write permission how can i replace that image with another image using same name ??